# How to syncronize the elimination of two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

Lets say I have two componentes that display a common component when I make a delete request to the api inside one of the componentes the other component does not get deleted until I refresh the browser how can I fix that such that the common component gets eliminated at the same time

here are the components:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getTasks } from "../api/task.api";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";

export function TaskLists() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTasks() {
      const res = await getTasks();
      console.log(res.data);
      setTasks(res.data);
    }
    loadTasks();
  }, []);

  const removeTask = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <TaskCard key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={removeTask} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { getTasks } from "../api/task.api";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";

export function Daycard({ hashv }) {
  let b = 0;
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTasks() {
      const res = await getTasks();
      console.log(res.data);
      setTasks(res.data);
    }
    loadTasks();
  }, []);

  const removeTask = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  const [hash, setHash] = useState(hashv);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (b === 0) {
      navigate(`/tasks-create?hash=${hash}`);
      console.log(`the hash is ${hash}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      className="col pb-5 bg-light border border-dark flex-grow-1"
      style={{ height: "auto" }}
    >
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.hash == hash) {
          b = 1;
          return <TaskCard key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={removeTask} />;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Behavior pressing delete inside the card:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts???

Comment: Why don't you use reducer ? I am wondering the "hash" meaning but it might be well if the hash is set as a state by dispatching.

Comment: @BobMartin I am not familiar with reducer how would you implement it?

Comment: Ok, at first I'd like to know about the meaning of hash or hashv.

Comment: @BobMartin hash is a unique identification for each element on the grid

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux or context.

Or make state in the main component including these two components which saves the task array. And use the state as props in these components.

When you press the remove button, then please run the remove function in the main component.

Then you'll get the result what you want.

```js
const MainComponent = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    return (
        <>
            ...
            <Daycard tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks} hashv={hashv}/>
            <TaskLists tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks}/>
            ...
        </>
    )
}

export function TaskLists({tasks, setTasks}) {
    
    //const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]); => Remove this line
    ...
}

export function Daycard({ hashv, tasks, setTasks }) {
    let b = 0;
    // const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);  => Remove this line
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting maincards.jsx:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at TaskLists (maincards.jsx:31:14)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)

Comment: You should check the props if it is defined. 

```  return (
    <div>
      {**tasks** && tasks.map((task) => (
        <TaskCard key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={removeTask} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );```